# Adding environment variables to server with Cypress Github Action

Tags: github-actions, cypress

I need to pass some environment variables to the server started in background by Cypress, eg under the `start` property below, as explained in the [Cypress documentation](https://github.com/cypress-io/github-action?tab=readme-ov-file#start-server):

```
  - name: Running e2e tests
    uses: cypress-io/github-action@v6
    with:
      start: sbt run
      command: npm run e2e:run-ci
```

If I use the `env` property, the variables are passed to the Cypress process, not the server process, eg:

```
  - name: Running e2e tests
    uses: cypress-io/github-action@v6
    with:
      start: sbt run
      command: npm run e2e:run-ci
      env: VAR=VAL
```

I also tried to replace the `start` value with "export VAR=VAL && sbt run" with no luck.

Comment: The point of the `env` _input_ is exactly to pass them to Cypress - to set general env vars use a regular step `env` as shown in https://github.com/cypress-io/github-action?tab=readme-ov-file#env

Comment: Does this answer your question? [cypress-io/github-action does not accept all environment variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69629218/cypress-io-github-action-does-not-accept-all-environment-variables)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer here: [cypress-io/github-action does not accept all environment variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69629218/cypress-io-github-action-does-not-accept-all-environment-variables?rq=2)

I needed to declare the env variables at the job level.

Answer (score 0):

By using the `command` parameter you have caused the `env` parameter to be ignored.

See [Custom test command](https://github.com/cypress-io/github-action?tab=readme-ov-file#custom-test-command):

> Caution: using the action parameter command causes multiple other parameters to be ignored including: auto-cancel-after-failures, browser, ci-build-id, command-prefix, component, config, config-file, env, group, headed, parallel, project, publish-summary, quiet, record, spec and tag.

Depending on the definition of your script `e2e:run-ci` you may just be able to delete the line `command: npm run e2e:run-ci`.

The Cypress GitHub Action is designed so that it runs Cypress e2e tests by default. No `command` parameter is normally necessary. If you need to modify how Cypress runs tests, then use the action parameters, not command line options of npx / npm etc..